# Не работает запрос в бд

Tags: php

Такой вопрос, не работает запрос бд таким образом `$mysqli->query("...");`, вместо этого приходится использовать `mysql_query("...");`
Вот весь код:

```
    function settings() {
    $data = array('nameproject' => 'name',
                  'titleproject' => 'title',
                  'emailadmin' => 'email',
                  'minlogin' => 'minlogin',
                  'maxlogin' => 'maxlogin',
                  'minwithdraw' => 'minsum',
                  'maxwithdraw' => 'maxsum',
                  'refpercent' => 'refpercent',
                  'exchange' => 'exchange',
                  'a1' => 'auth',
                  'r1' => 'reg',
                  'https' => 'https',
                  'stopwork' => 'stopwork'
    );
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET ".$value." = '".$_POST[$key]."'"); // вот и проблемное место, почему не работает $mysqli->query("..."); ?
        } else {
            mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET ".$value." = ''");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Расскажите ему кто-нибудь про variable scope.

Comment: @Ипатьев Тогда мне в функции получается нужно заново подключиться к бд?

Comment: Лучше передавать подключение в функцию, либо используйте процедурный стиль `mysqli_query( $query )`.

Answer (score 0):

собственно это бред какой то , функция все равно должна читать Конфиг даже если он не в теле функции .... т.к функция может принять любые значения из вне , но вернуть лишь те которые уже объявлены или возвращены самой функцией , единственное что , это то что ты мог вообще не заинклудить конфиг в файл

Comment: Собственно, это комментарий какой-то, а не ответ

Answer (score -3):

Нужно было в функции подключить файл с данными бд

```
function settings() {
include('../config.php'); // вот
$data = array('nameproject' => 'name',
              'titleproject' => 'title',
              'emailadmin' => 'email',
              'minlogin' => 'minlogin',
              'maxlogin' => 'maxlogin',
              'minwithdraw' => 'minsum',
              'maxwithdraw' => 'maxsum',
              'refpercent' => 'refpercent',
              'exchange' => 'exchange',
              'a1' => 'auth',
              'r1' => 'reg',
              'https' => 'https',
              'stopwork' => 'stopwork'
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($_POST[$key])) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET ".$value." = '".$_POST[$key]."'"); // вот и проблемное место, почему не работает $mysqli->query("..."); ?
    } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET ".$value." = ''");
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Это наихудший из возможных вариантов